# every hour one email posted by maestro.bounces.google.com - i want it to stop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I made a test script, for the first time.

Now, I get every hour (!) an  email send by 'maestro.bounces.google.com' with the title 'hello, world!' and in the email a link with;
'Link to your doc: https://docs.google.com/open?i' etc...

I tried to delete the document, in my drive, but it keeps appearing.

What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 3):

The script you tried has created a trigger to send a mail every hour, you should remove that trigger.

To do so, open / create any spreadsheet (or google document) and go to the script editor, from there go to ressources/all your triggers like illustrated below

[image]

then select the trigger that is sending the email, it should be a "timer trigger" with a (probably) relevant name, this window looks like this :

[image]

delete the trigger (or if you don't use scripts delete all of them) and close all these windows and you're done !